# What is the best practice using between Static methods in class & Non Static methods from Instantiated class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oop

I am working on one of my projects in MVC. I have created a common class which contains common methods.

To access all methods without instantiating i have created static methods. It saved creating instance of class all the time.
Is it best practice? Can i have explaining scenarios for both uses?

Comment: "Is it safe way / best practice to use methods? " - You _are_ using "methods" in both cases - static or not. Is it "safe" ? - Depends on your implementation and your definition of "safe". Is it best practice? To use static methods as default - not if you are following OOP clean code principles.

Comment: Depends on a few more factors, testability needs etc. As is this question is "too broad".

Comment: You need to edit your question to give the specific use case you have. I generally try to steer away from using static classes, but they have their uses sometimes.